# Как заполнить массив в node.js?

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, async-await, асинхронность

Подскажите, как мне заполнить массив arr в данном случае, просто он пустой у меня года вывожу результат, а AllScales выводится

```
    async.series (
  [
    function (callback) {
      DB.GetAllScales().then((AllScales) => {
        arrAllScales = AllScales;
        callback (null, AllScales);
      })

    },
    function (callback) {
      var arr = [];
      var TypeScales = [];
      async.eachSeries (arrAllScales,  Scales => {
        var NameScales = Scales['Name'];
         DB.GetTypeScales(NameScales).then(ArrtypeScales => {
          var Obj = {};
          Obj.NameScales = NameScales;
          Obj.TypeScales = ArrtypeScales;
          arr.push(Obj);
          console.log(arr.length)
        })
      })
      callback (null, arr);
    },
  ],
  function (err, result) {
    console.log (result);
  }
);
```